# Is possible to get the full json text that is sent to MSXML2.XMLHTTP?

Tags: json, xmlhttprequest, visual-foxpro

I'm working in VFP9 sending data (in json format) to an api restfull using MSXML2.XMLHTTP.
I need to know if is possible to get the full json text that is sent. At this moment I only can get the data who is send with the "send" method. I need to see the complete json text, with the headers, data, etc. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Alejandro

Comment: Would you mind closing your questions that are already answered.

Answer (score 1):

I use Microsoft.XMLHttp for REST API calls and works fine for me. Don't know if there would be any difference with MSXML2.XMLHTTP though.

First, here is a REST API test code (testing on typeicode.com):

```
clear
Local loXmlHttp As "Microsoft.XMLHTTP", lcUrl, postData,userID,id,title,body

*** We want to make this REST API call to typicode.com online test service:
***
*** https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
*** with parameters payload 
***
*** userId:12
*** title:From VFP
*** body:This is posted from VFP as a test
***
*** We do a POST call and want to 'create' a resource (insert call)

userID=12
title="From VFP"
body = "This is posted from VFP as a test"

Text to postData textmerge noshow
{
  "userId":<< m.userID >>,
  "title":"<< m.title >>",
  "body": "<< m.body >>"
}
endtext

lcUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'

loXmlHttp = Newobject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" )
loXmlHttp.Open( "POST" , m.lcUrl + '/posts', .F. )
loXmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json; charset=UTF-8")
loXmlHttp.Send( m.postData )

*** Print the URL we are sending our POST REST request
? m.lcUrl + '/posts'

? "==================================="
? "Post Test", loXmlHttp.Status
? loXmlHttp.responsetext
? "==================================="

*** We get the response code back with loXmlHttp.Status
*** Since we made a POST call to create a resource, on succesful call
*** we expect an 201-Created code back
*** We also print out the full JSON response from the call
*** Which looks like:
*** 
*** {
***     "userId": 12,
***     "title": "From VFP",
***     "body": "This is posted from VFP as a test",
***     "id": 101
*** }
*** 

*** Next line simply has a MessageBox to allow you to see the results
*** of the above call before continuing. It also reminds,
*** 200 is the OK and 201 is the Created response code.

MessageBox("Continue? API Codes: 200-OK, 201-Created",0,"REST API Test",10000) 

*** Then we try a new call to REST API with a GET call
*** asking to GET the post with id=3
*** If you have checked the typicode.com page there are some data there for testing:
*** 
***
*** /posts  100 posts
*** /comments   500 comments
*** /albums 100 albums
*** /photos 5000 photos
*** /todos  200 todos
*** /users  10 users
***
*** In our first call we ask for /posts/3
*** You could also go to this link in your browser to get the response back:
*** https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/3
***


clear
m.id = 3
loXmlHttp.Open( "GET" , Textmerge('<< m.lcUrl >>/posts/<< m.id >>'), .F. )
loXmlHttp.Send( )


? "Get post with ID X test", loXmlHttp.Status
? loXmlHttp.responsetext
? "==================================="


*** Again we have a MessageBox to allow you to see the results
*** of the above call before continuing.

MessageBox("Continue? API Codes: 200-OK, 201-Created",0,"REST API Test",10000) 
clear

*** Finally we try another GET call to REST API
*** asking to GET the comments done for the id=3
***
*** You could also go to this link in your browser to get the response back:
*** https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/3/comments
***



loXmlHttp.Open( "GET" , Textmerge('<< m.lcUrl >>/posts/<< m.id >>/comments'), .F. )
loXmlHttp.Send( )


? "Get test post X comments", loXmlHttp.Status
? loXmlHttp.responsetext
? "==================================="

MessageBox("Continue? API Codes: 200-OK, 201-Created",0,"REST API Test",10000) 
clear

*** Let's add another final request in this sample 
*** to GET, posts done by the user whose userId is 2

userId = 2

loXmlHttp = Newobject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" )
loXmlHttp.Open( "GET" , m.lcUrl + '/posts?userId=2', .F. )

loXmlHttp.Open( "GET" , Textmerge('<< m.lcUrl >>/posts?userId=<< m.userId >>'), .F. )
loXmlHttp.Send( )


? "==================================="
? "GET posts of user X's Test", loXmlHttp.Status
? loXmlHttp.responsetext
? "==================================="
```

To check what you are really sending, you can use tools like postman or ngrok. I will use ngrok here as it is simple. You can use it for free. Download and then at command prompt:

ngrok http 80

80 is default http port, you might choose say 8080, too. It would start a tunnel and on screen sho you the address, and also a web interface address, likely:

http://127.0.0.1:4040

In your browser, go to that adress. In VFP, change your URL for testing and run. ie: We would test the first call in the above sample like this (the address would be different for you, grab it from ngrok's web interface that you opened in browser):

```
clear
Local loXmlHttp As "Microsoft.XMLHTTP", lcUrl, postData,userID,id,title,body

userID=12
title="From VFP"
body = "This is posted from VFP as a test"

Text to postData textmerge noshow
{
  "userId":<< m.userID >>,
  "title":"<< m.title >>",
  "body": "<< m.body >>"
}
endtext

lcUrl = 'http://30dd0443adff.eu.ngrok.io'

loXmlHttp = Newobject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" )
loXmlHttp.Open( "POST" , m.lcUrl + '/posts', .F. )
loXmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json; charset=UTF-8")
loXmlHttp.Send( m.postData )
```

and run it. In ngrok web interface you would see the POST request done. Clicking it you would see details on right, summary, headers, RAW, ... tabs.

If you downloaded and use Postman (it is really great for working on REST API), you could create a POST request there and send, check response, get code in various languages etc but explaining it here is not as easy as the above ngrok. You should however check it if you would work with REST API and it takes 5 mins to start understanding making requests there.